# limit points in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

I'm taking a topology course with the textbook by Munkres. And I saw the definition of convergence of a sequence and limit point of a subset of a given topological space.

I have told in the class that those are analogues of the same thing, but I feel suspicious about this because we are not given any information about countability of shrinking open sets near each points.

I read carefully about the definitions of countability axioms and I made a guess that every limit point of a set is actually sequential limit of points of the set only when the space is 1st-countable.
But when I tried to make a counterexample for this one, I just struck because I have not yet seen even a topological space which is not 1st-countable!!

For clearity, let's put it this way: We collect all the limit points of a given set $E$ to form the closure $\bar{E}$ and similarly collect all the sequential limits of sequences in $E$ to form a sequential closure $E_s$. My question is whether
\begin{equation}
\bar{E} = E_s
\end{equation}
holds or not. And if not, then when this equality holds?

This is rather obvious that $E_s \subseteq \bar{E}$ for any topological space and the reverse inclusion is also true when the space is 1st-countable(by intersecting local bases). Is the 1st-countability the weakest condition for this purpose?

Comment: Relevant term: [Sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Comment: See [First-countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space) for examples of non-first-countable spaces.

Comment: E.g. the reals with all integers identified to a point (so with one non-trivial equivalence class) in the quotient topology, is a sequential but not first countable space.